# sending JSON data to client using writeandflush() from netty showing Invalid JSON type

Tags: java, flash, netty

I'm using java code for sending JSON data to flash for that I'm using netty server 4.0.23. 
By that I'm using two different data to send to the same client frequently. I used channel.writeAndFlush(). So far everything happens good, while receiving data in client both the data are merged together and gives Invalid Json.

I traced the sending data in java there it is in correct format. It is getting invalid while receiving in client side. The two different JSON data are merged into a single JSON Data, so that the Invalid Json type error is occuring. If I put timer delay in between the two data, then the data are correctly received in client side. How can I receive proper data without applying the delay inbetween the data while sending.....

I used the following pipelines

```
pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder());
pipeline.addLast(new StringEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("handler", new ServerHandler());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your client (the receiving part) does not handle the received JSON messages properly. TCP is streaming protocol, which means two writes on one side can be seen as one read on the other side.  For example, when a server sends "A" and "B", a client will not always see "A" and "B" but will sometimes see "AB", and it's fully fine.

To deal with this sort of situation, you need to 'frame' a message.  It is usually done in Netty by inserting a framing decoder.

In your case, the client is written in Flash, so you'd better simply use [XMLSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html) and let your server delimit each JSON message with NUL (0) byte.

If you are interested in framing, please read [the Netty user guide](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#wiki-h3-11).

Comment: Thanks alot for ur answer... can u suggest me to use framing decoder or give any sample program....

Comment: XMLSocket is working fine in connecting netty with flash. Thanks for your suggestion...